# Connecting a water heater to a solar charge controller

Tags: solar-cell

I have a lack of understanding problem, answer to which I could not successfully google out.

I have a 10W solar panel connected to a 12/24V 20W charge controller along with a 12V 7AH battery. I want to use this to heat an old (Man Sized) water heater without damaging the components. I do not know the specs of the heating element but im sure its a high power one.

I am okay if the water takes the whole day to get heated up or only gets lukewarm.

Is it possible that I 
(A) connect the heating element directly to the charge controller load pins? (Heater has a auto cut off)
(B) I will need an inverter in between to achieve this.

Or power is too low to connect the heater :(

Comment: You can easily calculate the temperature rise you'll get in any volume of water by completely discharging that battery, and decide if it is of any use to you.

Comment: Why do you want to use a solar panel to convert sunlight to electricity and then to heat, instead of a solar water heater which absorbs sunlight to heat up the water directly?

Comment: 10W is very low power.  At 10W energy transfer is 36000J/hr.  The thermal capacity of water is 4.18J/gK, and a typical 30 gal tank holds, say 114kg of water.  How many hours would it take to raise the water temperature 1 degree?

Comment: thanks for your inputs guys! @BrianDrummond I want to try that but just wondering if I should directly connect the element to the battery or use the charge controller and inverter.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev well this is because I have the solar panel and it doubles up as a battery charger in times of power outages. That was the necessity which prompted me to get into this project.

Comment: Run the numbers and I think you'll conclude it doesn't matter where you connect it - there just isn't enough power available.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without an inverter to boost the voltage you'll probably be giving the heating element only about 5% of its rated supply voltage. (I'm assuming a 'standard' 240V element)
5% voltage translates into 0.25% power...

So if I make a guess at the element being 2kW rated, then with your system it will only be producing 5W of heat. (Just an example, depends on your actual element)

I suspect you'd see a greater rise in temperature in a tank that size by just leaving the whole tank out in the sun rather than messing with photovoltaic solar panels.

Comment: I am ready to give it time, it practically has the whole day to get heated up. If I am to try connecting the element via the inverter (20W), will the inverter blow up or it would just under perform?

Comment: But you don't have an inverter, you have a charge controller. Even if you did have a 20W inverter, it would either shut down due to overload or it would simply die.

Comment: Leave the tank out in the sun and do as the Rolling Stones suggest - 'Paint it Black'.